# Handling and Mapping Runtime Exceptions in REST Resource to JAX-RS Response

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have a RESTful web application that connects to a database and has the normal REST, business logic service and persistence layers. What is the JAX-RS standard approach to handling Runtime errors, like database connection is not available, in a RESTful layer? I believe the approach I have below, where I wrap any call to my service/persistence layers with a try/catch for the Throwable and throw my custom MyAppRuntimeException is a bit awkward.  Any suggestions?

**RESTful Service:**

```
@Path("service")
@Consumes({"application/json"})
@Produces({"application/json"})
public class MyResource {
  @GET
  @Path("/{id}")
  public Response getPage(@PathParam("id") long id){
    Object test=null;
    try {
         test = ...
      //call business logic service method here which makes a call to database and populates test instance
    } catch (Throwable e) {
      throw new MyAppRuntimeException("custom error message string");
    }

    if(test != null){
        return Response.ok(test).build();
    }else{
        return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }

  }
}
```

**Custom Exception:**

```
public class MyAppRuntimeException extends RuntimeException {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


  public MyAppRuntimeException(String message) {
    super(message);
  }

  public MyAppRuntimeException(String message, Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
  }


}
```

**Exception JAX-RS Response Mapper:**

```
@Provider
public class MyAppRuntimeExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<MyAppRuntimeException> {

  private static final String ERROR_KEY = "DATA_ERROR";

  @Override
  public Response toResponse(MyAppRuntimeException exception) {

    ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(ERROR_KEY, exception.getMessage(), null);
    return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(errorMessageDTO).build();
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you have control over the exceptions that come from the business logic? You could map those exceptions directly, and avoid the catch Throwable which could hide code (e.g. null pointer exceptions) and performance (e.g. Out of memory errors) from you. Also is Forbidden an appropriate description of the state for a response code as opposed to say 'service unavailable'? Your requirements would dictate such, but something to think about. :)

Comment: By default, uncaught exceptions I believe should result in an internal server error which could be ok too depending on your needs / contract you want to define with your restful clients.

Comment: You can also throw a WebApplicationException if test = null, thereby allowing you to just return The value test in the OK case.

Comment: @Charlie - I do have control of some of the known possible exceptions that could occur in the business logic and those are being thrown and mapped using a different exception and mapper class. I would suppose Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR is more appropriate than Forbidden or service unavailable since a NullPointerException doesn't mean its not available.

Comment: @c12 why don't you declare your own `ExceptionMapper` handling generic `Exception`. Then just declare that `getPage(..) throws Exception` and let mapper handle thrown exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

Just have your exception class extend `WebApplicationException` and throw it wherever you like. You can see in the example below that you can customize the response in whatever way is necessary. Happy coding!

Note: this example handles `403` errors, but you can easily create exceptions to handle `500`, `503`, etc.

```
package my.package.name;

import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Http401NotAuthorizedException extends WebApplicationException implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  public Http401NotAuthorizedException(String msg){
    super(
      Response
        .status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN)
        .header("Pragma", "no-cache, no-store")
        .header("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store")
        .header("Expires", "0")
        .entity(msg)
        .build()
    );
  }
}
```